# Why is my File I/O in VSCode not working properly?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, file-io, ide, cs50

Edited for more clarity.

Currently having problems with file handling in C using VSCode.

In CS50, we use the browser-based CS50 IDE to answer problem sets. I tried using Visual Studio Code to compile the same code using `gcc test.c -o test` and it does. But the problem is that when I run `./test card.raw`, it does not run as expected. `card.raw` is the input file which contains 50 `.jpg` images, more about it below.

CS50 IDE uses

`clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    test.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o test`,

but I'm not sure if that is the difference. The code, both the same in CS50 IDE and VSCode, is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;
const int FAT = 512;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./ filename.raw\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open file
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be read.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Initializing a buffer
    BYTE buffer[FAT];

    // Counter for filename
    int counter = 0;

    // Pointer declaration for new images
    FILE *img = NULL;

    char *filename = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));

    while (fread(buffer, 1, FAT, file) != 0)
    {
        // Checks if JPEG
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // Sets up the filename
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            counter++;
        }
        
        if (img != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, FAT, img);
        }
    }
    // Closes all opened files
    fclose(img);

    fclose(file);

    // Frees memory from malloc
    free(filename);

    return 0;
}
```

In this particular code, the input file `card.raw` is provided for us. It contains 50 `.jpg` files inside it. So, I expect 50 output `.jpg` files, named `000.jpg`, `001.jpg`, and so on up to `049.jpg` that can really be inspected visually like a normal `.jpg` file.

It does it fine in the CS50 IDE. When I run `./test card.raw` in CS50 IDE, it outputs 50 `.jpg` files as expected. But when using VSCode, it only produces 1 `.jpg` file, named `000.jpg`. When opened, it says file format is unsupported, or is corrupted.

`test.c`, `test.exe`, `card.raw` are all in the same directory, just as how it is in the CS50 IDE.

I also notice that the compiled code in VSCode is using the `.exe` file format, as in `test.exe`. But when I downloaded the compiled code from the CS50 IDE, it is not in `.exe`, as in only `test`.

I guess what I'm trying to achieve here is I want to be more comfortable using more popular IDEs like VSCode or Atom as I slowly remove the "training wheels" the CS50 IDE provides.

Comment: Pretty hard to say what the problem is without seeing the code or even the problem statement (guess - bugs in your code resulting in inconsistent and unpredictable results). Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also include the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: @kaylum Alright, do I make a new post about it, or does "answer your question" to update the question would suffice?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69067292/edit) the post to update it.

Comment: Multiple things spring to mind immediately. First, this code leaks opened `FILE*` pointers like a sieve leaks rainwater. Only the *last* one is ever actually closed by your program; the rest are left to the program termination to flush (assuming they opened correctly in the first place).  Second, if you're going to perform error checking, then actually do something in error states. Checking `img` against `NULL` is certainly good, but there is no `else`, so if the open failed you have no clue *why*. Regarding VSCode, check your launch.json config and make sure your working directory is correct.

Comment: I also tried `./test.exe card.raw` but to no avail.

Comment: I assume you are using Windows (note: it sounds like cs50 online ide is possibly not Windows so that's one difference)? Try opening the file in binary mode as Windows requires that.

Comment: ^^^^ e.g. `fopen(argv[1], "rb");`

Comment: @kaylum @WhozCraig I did that, as well as `fopen(filename, "wb")`, and that solves the problem!

Comment: @kaylum indeed, CS50 IDE is Linux-based.

Comment: @kaylum yes sir, it does. always use `b` mode when in windows, although i never knew it was the issue to begin with